# Workbench: How can I reorder display of Workbench Tabs?

Tags: workbench

I'm running Workbench, workbench access, workbench moderation and workbench media on Drupal 7. 
I added a new state "Needs publish" for "Waiting to be published", which is under "**Configuration > Workbench > Workbench Moderation > States tab**". Also, I cloned the "Needs review page" view for "Needs publish page"(just changing the filter "Workbench Moderation: State" to "Needs Pulish"). However, the new tab I have for "Needs publish" is in between "My Drafts" and "Needs Review".

Question: How can I move the new tab "Needs Publish" after "Needs review"?

--- Added screenshot on July 23, 2014 at 1:49pm
[image]

Answer (score 0):

under the view `Table Display` Settings. You should be able to assign placement of the columns there.

See the `Format` > `Table` > `Settings` at the left:
[image]

Then assign fields to certain columns here. The ordering of these columns by default is the ordering of the `Fields` defined in the View.
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wanna change the Main Tab that show on "My Workbench". See updated screenshot for details.

Comment: those appear to be `menu local tasks` in drupal. you would use `hook_menu_alter` to change the weight of that tab to move it left to right.

Comment: I found there is a "Weight" setting under "Menu" on Views. Thanks tenken